# React bootstrap Table Search

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `react-bootstrap` `Table`

filteredData function should return `searchTerm` matches record from the data.

I am getting empty data on search now.

How to loop through Object and return true If any of the searchTerm match?

```js
import { Table, Pagination, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

```js
const dummyData = [
    { consumerID: 1, consumerName : 'John', emailId: 25, mobileno:'234567' , vehiclePlte:'abcg', SchemeCashback:'abcg' , Cashbackalance:'abcg' , status :'approved',createdDate: new Date('2024-03-18'), edit:'edite',delete:'delete'},
    { consumerID: 1, consumerName : 'John', emailId: 25, mobileno:'234567' , vehiclePlte:'abcg', SchemeCashback:'abcg' , Cashbackalance:'abcg' , status :'approved',createdDate: new Date('2024-03-17'), edit:'edite',delete:'delete'},
   
    { consumerID: 1, consumerName : 'John', emailId: 25, mobileno:'234567' , vehiclePlte:'abcg', SchemeCashback:'abcg' , Cashbackalance:'abcg' , status :'approved',createdDate: new Date('2024-03-16'), edit:'edite',delete:'delete'},
    { consumerID: 1, consumerName : 'John', emailId: 25, mobileno:'234567' , vehiclePlte:'abcg', SchemeCashback:'abcg' , Cashbackalance:'abcg' , status :'approved',createdDate: new Date('2024-03-15'), edit:'edite',delete:'delete'},
    { consumerID: 1, consumerName : 'John', emailId: 25, mobileno:'234567' , vehiclePlte:'abcg', SchemeCashback:'abcg' , Cashbackalance:'abcg' , status :'approved',createdDate: new Date('2024-03-14'), edit:'edite',delete:'delete'},
    { consumerID: 1, consumerName : 'John', emailId: 25, mobileno:'234567' , vehiclePlte:'abcg', SchemeCashback:'abcg' , Cashbackalance:'abcg' , status :'approved',createdDate: new Date('2024-03-13'), edit:'edite',delete:'delete'},
    { consumerID: 1, consumerName : 'John', emailId: 25, mobileno:'234567' , vehiclePlte:'abcg', SchemeCashback:'abcg' , Cashbackalance:'abcg' , status :'approved',createdDate: new Date('2024-03-12'), edit:'edite',delete:'delete'},
    { consumerID: 1, consumerName : 'John', emailId: 25, mobileno:'234567' , vehiclePlte:'abcg', SchemeCashback:'abcg' , Cashbackalance:'abcg' , status :'approved',createdDate: new Date('2024-03-11'), edit:'edite',delete:'delete'},
    { consumerID: 1, consumerName : 'John', emailId: 25, mobileno:'234567' , vehiclePlte:'abcg', SchemeCashback:'abcg' , Cashbackalance:'abcg' , status :'approved',createdDate: new Date('2024-03-19'), edit:'edite',delete:'delete'},
    { consumerID: 1, consumerName : 'John', emailId: 25, mobileno:'234567' , vehiclePlte:'abcg', SchemeCashback:'abcg' , Cashbackalance:'abcg' , status :'approved',createdDate: new Date('2024-03-22'), edit:'edite',delete:'delete'},
    { consumerID: 1, consumerName : 'John', emailId: 25, mobileno:'234567' , vehiclePlte:'abcg', SchemeCashback:'abcg' , Cashbackalance:'abcg' , status :'approved',createdDate: new Date('2024-03-24'), edit:'edite',delete:'delete'},
     // Add more dummy data as needed
  ];

  const [data, setData] = useState(dummyData);
```

```js
const filteredData = useMemo(() => {
  return data.filter(row => 
    Object.entries(row).every(([key, value]) => {

      if (key === 'createdDate') {
        // Check if createdDate is null or matches the search date
        return !searchDate || value.toISOString().split('T')[0] === searchDate;
      }
      return value.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
    })
  );
}, [data, searchTerm, searchDate]);
```

```js
<input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Search..."
                value={searchTerm}
                className='rounded border border-1 border-solid border-dark'
                onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
              />
```